# How can I access the Advanced Security Options Tab from .net?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a problem with regarding Active Directory programming.I need to access the Security Tab to assign “Permissions for SELF” with .net.How can I do that?

Comment: You don't want to do this. This tab is UI. You want to modify ACLs programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do with the `ActiveDirectorySecurity` class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectorysecurity.aspx.